# pass string variable from html file to JSP

Tags: javascript, jquery, string, jsp, post

I am trying to pass a string to a jsp file, and then I hope the jsp file will do something with the string. I don't know jsp though. I just want to make sure that my logic is correct. My code "works", but I want to make sure of what it does.  I think I am posting the val of the string to browser's memory and calling the test.jsp file. Is that what is happening?  Or should I do something completely different?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
<title>Page Title</title>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        var qString = '';
        $('#execute').click(function(){
        qString = $('#query-string').val();
        console.log(qString);
        $.post('test.jsp',qString);
        });
    });


</script>

</head>

<body>
<section>
    <label for="query-string">Enter your query here!</label>
    <input type="text" id="query-string">
        <button id="execute">Execute</button> 

</section>



</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

send your value as object and not string

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
    var qString = '';
    $('#execute').click(function(){
      qString = $('#query-string').val();
      console.log(qString);
      $.post('test.jsp',{qString:qString},function(data){
         //your stuff .. 
         alert('successfull');
      });
});
```

so this will post your values with a name `qString` to test.jsp page ..

`{qString:qString}` here key (qString) is the name by which the data is posted to jsp page (it can be anything) example `{test:qString}` , here data is posted as test so in jsp page you have to get the posted data by `test`...

`function(data){....});` this is a callback function which is called when your post method is successfully called and returns some data from the server